# "This question body does not meet our quality standards"

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm trying to write [a simple question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172650/what-do-i-lose-if-i-am-attacked) that I could not find a full answer to after searching. I wrote it to be short and straight to the point, about two lines long, and it has no problematic grammar. I tried posting it and was not allowed, giving me the message below:

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make
>   sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you
>   have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

I then added a few unnecessary words and it was allowed.

What do you think of the minimum character restrictions imposed here? What do you think of this error message, which triggers based off of the number of characters, but tells the user to fix their grammar and describe the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a network-wide policy, and the details of the quality algorithm are intentionally vague.  You can read more over at [Meta.Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards).

Comment: Also check out the list of linked questions - lots and lots of people have said similar things about it, and the response from SE is generally "deal with it."

Comment: That's unfortunate. I realized it applied to other sites in the network too, but I didn't think it was something that we had no control over.